# Bluemix Watson Conversation API to manage intents, entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson

The documented API only allows interaction with the Watson Conversation service once it is configured. Is there any API which will allow the configuration. For example create intents, entities etc...

Comment: Quick update on this request. We have since released APIs for Intents and Workspaces. Entities coming shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Good questions and we agree.  We have plans shortly to expose a lower level set of APIs that will address your concerns. Brian

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time the APIs for what you want to do are not publicly exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close out this question. The [API for Watson Assistant (formerly Watson Conversation) can be seen here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl). The [Watson Developer SDKs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/) support that API.

To see the API in action there are several examples. I wrote a [tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) demonstrating some of the API calls and a so-called [EgoBot](https://github.com/data-henrik/bluemix-egobot/) that mutates during the dialog, i.e., adds objects by using that API.