# API to update entities for IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

Is there an API to update entities, values and synonyms. I wish to add values and synonyms to entities as and when they are created in my database. Also I would have hundreds and thousands of values for entities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluemix Watson Conversation API to manage intents, entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635955/bluemix-watson-conversation-api-to-manage-intents-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /workspace endpoint might do what you want.  Take a look at https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#update_workspace

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to update Entities, Intents or the Dialog Flow for the Conversation service. Instead you need to use the tooling.

Comment: by "tooling" did you mean manually type or upload CSV from the UI?

Comment: also, is there a plan to introduce an API soon?

Answer (score 0):

The Conversation tool is available for your service instances at https://www.ibmwatsonconversation.com or from the service details page in Bluemix (which you get to by clicking your service instance).

There are plans to expose more APIs that might address your request.